# Setting no "fast forward" as the default when merging. Is this wise and what are some of the consequences?

Tags: git, git-merge

So I generally follow the workflow of master branch is for production code only, while all development is done on the development branch which is where I merge all feature branches. I like `git merge --no-ff` because it records the commit history of the feature branch when merging into development. However, I've seen many warnings about this approach when setting no fast forward by default in git config.

Has anyone had problems with this approach? Can you specifically explain the reasons this is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one downside to setting --no-ff as default would be when working with a team you may encounter cases where you want to do a fast forward merge to update a feature branch another team member collaborated on with you.

It might be a better approach to create an alias to handle merges with --no-ff